# Solr unable to search on fields?

Tags: docker-compose, solr

I have installed **Solr** as a docker image and can create cores and upload some test JSON.

I then want to search on this, but I can't, in this case I want to find the id where it matches. I enter the q filter text and then hit execute but it still lists all the json results! what am I missing?

[image]

I can query it in a url as follows though!? so seems like the front end is messed up somehow?

[image]

Comment: Hello, if you look in your first printscreen (in both url and params) -> q=*:*. So the result is correct.

Comment: O! so the left values are not working when I hit the execute button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue was in my **docker-compose.yml** file, I had these extra lines which seem to cause this issue, redoing the instance without this, I can happily query the data.

```
command:
  - solr-precreate
  - gettingstarted
```